# Converting a float to float*

Tags: c++

I have QStandardItem* list in my code

```
QList<QStandardItem*> lst
```

Now this is acceptable and works

```
float a = lst[0]->text().toFloat();
```

However the following does not work

```
float* a = &(lst[0]->text().toFloat());
```

I get an intellisense error stating

> Expression must be an lvalue or a function designator

I need a pointer here since I am using an external library that requires a reference that looks like this

```
 some_class.add_variable(const std::string& variable_name, float& t);
```

So if I get a pointer I could simply pass it as *a

Any suggetsions on how I could resolve this issue ?

Comment: there's no conection between a function expecting a *reference* and you being required to dereference a pointer

Comment: If that did work, what would the pointer actually point to? Think about it, there is no `float` for the `float*` to point to. (If there was, what would its scope be?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right hand side is what's called a *temporary*. It is an object which will not exist after the end of the current expression. For obvious reasons, you can't take the address of temporaries; after the expression ends you'd have an invalid pointer.

What you could do is this:

```
float a = lst[0]->text().toFloat();
float* aPtr = &a;
```

That will safely make a copy of the temporary value (or in C++11, it may `move` the temporary), and you can then take a reference to your local, non-temporary variable.

Comment: however I would like aPtr to still be valid after the scope of the function ends. In ur case aPtr will not work after a runs out of scope

Comment: @MistyD Do whatever you'd normally do to keep a pointer valid. `malloc` the memory and copy the value into there, make it a class variable or global variable, etc.

Comment: @MistyD You probably don't want this pointer to be valid for very long as the value of `lst[0]->text` can change and the value pointed to won't reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Use `float a = lst[0]->text().toFloat();` and simply pass it as `&a` to the library function.

Comment: I dont want to do that as `a` is in local scope while lst[0]->text().toFloat() is in global scope

Comment: @MistyD I don't see why that's a problem.

Comment: @MistyD That doesn't matter for subsequent, synchronous function calls! It'll just work fine here.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the address of a temporary value returned by a function is not going to work. This value is supposed to be assigned to an lvalue variable.

Why do you want the address of the float instead of the actual value?

You should only be dealing with addresses of, or pointers to values that have been saved somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your external function does NOT need an address, it takes a REFERENCE, so you don't need a pointer.

However, if you really need the pointer to a local variable:

```
float x = something...;
some_function(&x);
```

will give you what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Take care: `float* a = &(lst[0]->text().toFloat());` will give you *undefined behaviour* if you refer to `a` following this statement. This is because the *anonymous temporary* (the float returned by `.tofloat()`) will be out of scope after the statement and `a` will be invalidated; *i.e.* will not point to anything meaningful.

You should write `float a = lst[0]->text().toFloat()`, and pass `&a` to the function. That is, keep `a` in scope for as long as you need it.

Comment: @MistyD - oops; typo ;-)